# Correct order of tasks for WSE 2016 domain migration?

Tags: active-directory, domain, migration, windows-server-essentials

Some background:

- I had a standalone non-WSE 2016 server (SERVER3) that contained a single-domain Active Directory forest (as well as the FSMO roles, of course).
- I clean-installed a new WSE 2016 server (SERVER2) and ran the WSE Configuration Wizard.
- I then had two standalone servers, each with its own unique single-domain Active Directory forest.
- I demoted SERVER2 and removed the Active Directory role
- On SERVER2 I joined the domain of SERVER3
- I promoted SERVER2 to a DC
- I transferred the FSMO roles to SERVER2

I think I may have goofed here, because now the WSE Media Streaming Service on SERVER2 won't start, claiming 'bad password' (Event ID 7038, not [7041](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/post-deployment-configuration-task-fail)) for the `MediaAdmin$` MSA in the System Event Log. (Note that the MSA was also present on SERVER3 before I started all this, the AD forest there having been replicated from an earlier Essentials server.)

More detail on the MSA problem is [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1087553).

I propose to start over and redo it all, this time joining SERVER2 to SERVER3's domain and promoting to a DC *before* running the wizard (the wizard, in turn, will create the MSA and related service). I believe this is the more correct way to do it. Correct me, please, if I am mistaken in this.

But in the meantime, before I begin, I have some questions: (Should I repost them individually, including this background for each one?)

1. Did I create this MSA problem myself, by configuring DC/FSMO *after* running the wizard, instead of before?
2. Should I delete the `MediaAdmin$` MSA from SERVER3's AD before joining its domain with the new SERVER2?
3. Is it OK to run the wizard on a DC that already holds the FSMO roles?

Hopefully the answers here will be yes, yes and yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple DC for a domain.

If you mean to do a migration your correct step should look that way;

[image]

***I would add another step, 4.1, to test if the replication and all active directory is replicated correctly.***

The part that is not wrote is that even if you have two domain named the same way, and account named the same in both, the GUID will not match, so it's a make over you describe, not a migration. As you ask for a migration, I corrected your step to be more a migration.

Comment: Yes, thank you, my research has revealed steps right in line with what you're recommending. But my uncertainty is more about the MSA and the WSE Configuration Wizard bits, particularly questions #2 and #3.